# Can GeoWebCache response GeoTiff format image

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, geowebcache

I use GeoServer integrated with GeoWebCache.

There are some default formats:jpg\png\png8\gif, but no GeoTiff - how can I add this format.

I develop 3D-GIS client, and my client only supports jpg and GeoTiff.

When I Get Map with "FORMAT=image/jpeg", the empty area of result jpeg file is not clear,there is always some bad pixels.

My questions are:

1. can I get the GeoTiff image?
2. can I get rid of the bad pixel?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Getting GeoTiff through GeoWebCache isn't possible at the moment, although I don't think it would be too hard to add.  You can make a feature request or submit a patch via GWC's [GitHub page](https://github.com/GeoWebCache).  There may be changes needed on the GeoServer side as well.

Given the available formats at the moment, the only way to have transparency would be to use PNG or GIF so you'd have to add support for that to your client.